# Should you write "public virtual" or "virtual public" in virtual inheritance?

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-inheritance

Based on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_inheritance

```
class Animal 
{
...
};

// Two classes virtually inheriting Animal:
class Mammal : public virtual Animal 
{
...
};
```

I also saw books use the following syntax,

```
class Mammal : virtual public Animal 
{
...
};
```

Question> Which is one the C++ standard?

Thank you

Comment: FYI this isn't multiple inheritance, this is virtual inheritance that you're asking about.

Comment: @Adam, we should use virtual inheritance from the base class when we use multiple inheritance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From **ISO/IEC 14882:2003(E) - 10.1**

A list of base classes can be specified in a class definition using the notation:

```
base-clause:
    : base-specifier-list

base-specifier-list:
    base-specifier
    base-specifier-list , base-specifier

base-specifier:
    ::opt nested-name-specifieropt class-name
    virtual access-specifier opt ::opt nested-name-specifieropt class-name
    access-specifier virtual opt ::opt nested-name-specifieropt class-name

access-specifier:
    private
    protected
    public
```

Notice that either is recommended.

Comment: @q0987 - Google search on mentioned standard name, you should be able to find one :)

Comment: this is the grammar, but what of the semantics, ie is the meaning equivalent ?

Answer (score 4):

Both are standard.  Use whichever the local coding conventions require.